# Flutter Taking to me MainPage (root page (/) ) Every time when i back from any page

Tags: flutter

Flutter Taking to me MainPage (root page (/) ) Every time when i back from any page

**main.dart**

This is my application main page

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'routes.dart' as router;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
        title: "Leuke App",
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
    ),
      );
    }
 }
```

**routes.dart**

This is my application route

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/Login.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/MyProfile.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/SignUpDOB.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/SignUpOTP.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/SignUpSendOTP.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/SlidingUpPanelContainer.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/VideoRecorder.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/editProfile.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/MainPage.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/pages/SignUpPage.dart';

Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  var arguments = settings.arguments;
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage());
    case 'login':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login());
    case 'sing-up':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage());
    case 'sign-up-dob':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpDOB());
    case 'login':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login());
    case 'sign-up-send-otp':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpSendOTP(arguments));
    case 'sign-up-otp':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpOTP(arguments));
    case 'home':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage());
    case 'camera':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VideoRecorder());
    case 'edit-profile':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditProfile());
    case 'my-profile':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyProfile());
    default:
  }
}
```

**MainPage.dart**

This is my application Main Page that show spash screen and check if user is login then goto
HomePage other wise Login Page
import 'dart:async';

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:leukeApp/services/SessionManager.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  var loggedInUser = new Map();
  final SessionManager sessions = new SessionManager();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkInternetConnection(true);
  }

  redirectToLoginOrHome() async {
    await sessions.getUserInfo().then((checkLoggedInUservalue) {
      loggedInUser = checkLoggedInUservalue;
      if (loggedInUser['user_id'] > 0) {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home');
    });
      } else {
    setState(() {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'login');
    });
      }
    });
  }

  Widget dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
      child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 18.0,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0, right: 8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff2e2f34),
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black26,
            blurRadius: 0.0,
            offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          ),
        ]),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
        Center(
            child: Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new AssetImage("assets/images/no-internet.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ) //
            ),
        Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          child: new Text("Internet Connection Error",
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: Color(0xfff5ae78),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ) //
            ),
        Center(
            child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          child: new Text(
              "Please check your internet connectivity and try again",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15.0,
            color: Colors.white,
              )),
        ) //
            ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: Container(
              height: 45,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color(0xffec4a63), Color(0xff7350c7)],
            begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 1),
            end: FractionalOffset(0.4, 4),
            stops: [0.1, 0.7],
              )),
              child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Retry',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontFamily: 'RockWellStd',
              ),
            ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              checkInternetConnection(false);
            },
          ),
        ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
      ),
    );
  }

  checkInternetConnection(bool showPopup) async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
    if (showPopup) {
      showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    ),
      );
    }
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 700), () => redirectToLoginOrHome());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Color(0XFF15161a),
      ),
      Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/gif-logo.gif',
        width: 200,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/logo-name.gif',
        width: 200,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the context of the Main page used in Navigator.pushNamed() was never changed. The `context` of the current page should be used on

```java
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage());
```

to add the current page to the stack of routes. More details can be read in the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#3-navigate-to-the-second-screen).

Comment: Can you edited my code? where i use this statement?

Comment: You want to say that on each page i have to use MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()); rather than Navigator.pushNamed(context, ''); ??